# How to use CASE statement in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need the following output.

```
NE 50
SE 80
```

I am using pig query to count the country based on zone.

```
c1 = group country by zone;
c2 = foreach c1 generate COUNT(country.zone), (
case country.zone
when 1 then 'NE'
else 'SE'
);
```

But I am not able to achieve my output. I am getting error like the following:

```
2016-03-30 13:57:16,569 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1039: (Name: Equal Type: null Uid: null)incompatible types in Equal Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(zone:int)  right hand side:int
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1459370643493.log
```

But I was able to do using following query.

```
c2 = foreach c1 generate group, COUNT(country.zone);
```

This will give following output:

```
(1,50)
(2,80)
```

How can I add NE instead of 1 and SE instead of 2? I thought using CASE would help but I am getting error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Pig 0.12.0 Version** now supports CASE expression.

```
c2 = FOREACH c1 GENERATE (CASE group
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'NE' 
                              WHEN 2 THEN 'SE'
                              WHEN 3 THEN 'AE'
                              ELSE 'VR' END), COUNT(country.zone);
```

**Older Pig Versions**

Pig does not have a case statement.Your best option is to use UDF.If the group values are limited to only two then you can use [bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators+and+More) operator to check the value

```
c2 = foreach c1 generate (group == 1 ? 'NE' : 'SE'), COUNT(country.zone);
```

If you have multiple values then use this.I've used test values to generate the output.

**Input**

[image: Input]

```
c2 = FOREACH c1 GENERATE (group == 1 ? 'NE' : 
                         (group == 2 ? 'SE' :
                         (group == 3 ? 'AE' : 'VR'))), COUNT(country.zone);
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: What if I need the output as follows:
NE 50
SE 80
AE 50
VR 40
How to use foreach statement to compare the zone for all fours and count countries based on them?

Comment: @BXT what are the corresponding values for NE,SE AE,VR? 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your such a clear explanation. I did using CASE statement as in Hive and got confused. I really appreciate your work. Do you also have blog for Big data and hadoop so that it will be easy for me learning as I am beginner?

Comment: @BXT Glad it helped. I am beginner too :)

Answer (score 0):

In Pig 12 and later, you can use case statement in pig

In your case, country.zone is a bag and you cant compare it to an int

Answer (score 0):

With above posted answer getting this error.

```
mismatched input ')' expecting END.
```

So updating a working code:

```
c2 = FOREACH c1 GENERATE (CASE group
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'NE'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'SE'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'AE'
                            ELSE 'VR' END), COUNT(country.zone);
```

Output:

```
(NE, 50)
(SE, 80)
(AE, 30)
```